# css3 pie doesn't work

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
ul.topMenu li.language .dropDown {
    background: url(../img/arrow-dropdown.png) no-repeat 137px 9px;
    border: 1px solid #c5c2be;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

the border radius works great in firefox, chrome and IE9, but for some reason, ie8 can't recognize it even though I have the PIE.htc file in the same directory as the index.html.
What am I missing? I only have the PIE.htc file included in the project, do I need the other files from pie as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can try just to put `position:relative;`